# Laravel Migration issue General Error: 3780

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have a developer that pretty much abandoned a project.  I have the code from the server and I'm trying to get it working on my local environment.  I am trying to get it to migrate, but I keep getting a referencing issue and I've looked at the posts and have tried everything from adding the disableForeignKeyConstraints(); to the composer dump-autoload etc.  But still keep getting

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'role_user_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `role_user` add constraint `role_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'role_user_user_id_foreign' are incompatible.

I saw it said incompatible so I tried adding the unsigned(); to the user creation, but still no dice.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

and the user create migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->boolean('activated')->default(false);
            $table->string('token');
            $table->ipAddress('signup_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('signup_confirmation_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('signup_sm_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('admin_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('updated_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('deleted_ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: is your `users` table created before your `role_user` table? What are the names of both migration files (including the timestamp)?

Comment: yes user is first 2014_10_12_000000_create_user_table.php and 2016_01_15_105324_create_role_user_table.php

Comment: Strange indeed.. if you remove your foreign, it runs fine?

Comment: Try replace `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();` by `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These items didn't work and since I had a copy of the database I did a reverse migration [info found here for migration generator](https://www.5balloons.info/create-migration-files-from-existing-database-in-laravel/)

Even then I ran into class issues, I simply removed the migration files out of a vendor folder the developer had used and was able to then run the new migration.  Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your role_user table needs your user table to be created first.
Lets assume your migration files look like this :

1) create_users_table_migration.php
2) create_roles_table_migration.php

They would be stored in laravelProject/database/migrations

Try running just your user migration by the following command :

```
php artisan migrate --path=laravelProject/database/migrations/create_users_table_migration.php
```

and then by migrating your user_roles table by :

```
php artisan migrate --path=laravelProject/database/migrations/create_users_table_migration.php
```

Comment: user is being created first 2014_10_12 (prefix on user) vs. 2016_01_15 on roles